# Como extrair apenas os valores do JSON retirando as chaves

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Eu tenho um array com alguns ids, o objeto de retorno da minha requisição ao WebService é como mostra o trecho de código número 1.

Queria saber se tem alguma maneira via jQuery, de extrair apenas os valores e deixar o meu JSON como mostra o objeto do segundo trecho de código:

1. Como está:

   ```
      [{
               "id": "1"
           }, {
               "id": "2"
           }, {
               "id": "3"
           }, {
               "id": "4"
           }, {
               "id": "5"
           }]
   ```
2. Como eu queria que estivesse:

   ```
   ["1","2","3","4","5"]
   ```

Comment: É necessário transformar primeiro a string em um objeto, utilizando por exemplo JSON.parse() e depois vc pode percorrer o array e obter os ids.

Comment: Mas ele já está em formato JSON, fiz a requisição ao webservice via angular e ele me devolve utilizando  echo json_encode($resposta)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) para extrair apenas os `ids`.

Exemplo:

```js
let dados = [
    { "id": "1" },
    { "id": "2" },
    { "id": "3" },
    { "id": "4" },
    { "id": "5" }
];

let ids = dados.map(item => item.id);

console.log(ids);
```

Se você não puder usar [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), outro exemplo:

```js
var dados = [
    { "id": "1" },
    { "id": "2" },
    { "id": "3" },
    { "id": "4" },
    { "id": "5" }
];

var ids = dados.map(function(item) {
    return item.id;
});

console.log(ids);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado era isso mesmo, eu usei algum termo errado ou tem algo que eu possa melhorar na pergunta pra quem for pesquisar entender de maneira mais clara e objetiva?

Comment: Você pode trocar "Eu tenho um JSON" por "Eu tenho um array". Não faz diferença de onde veio, a sua dúvida é como extrair os dados deste array para um outro